# Django .filter() for imagefields

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have 6 or more images saved in a model in Django. I want to iterate over these to create a carousel in Bootstrap. So far I have everything working as expected however I cannot seem to create the for loop to return more than one picture.

My views.py looks like this

```
def slideshow(request, pk):
   retdict = {'cars': Sales.objects.filter(id=pk)}
   return render(request, "website/slideshow.html", retdict)
```

and the slideshow.html (without all the bootstrap carousel code) looks like

```
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    {% for pic in cars %}
    {% if forloop.counter == 1 %}
    <div class="item active">
    {% else %}
    <div class="item">
    {% endif %}
        <img src="{{ pic.photo1.url }}" alt="Image">
  </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

I realise that the photo1.url is the incorrect code to type as this references the name of the file in the database. I want to be able to call many images but I am unsure how to get the correct .url for each iteration of the for loop.

I am trying to recreate a webpage I have already created www.expatcarsaleskl.com however this takes a lot of work and each slideshow page (when you click on a picture) requires a hard coded file. Moving this to Django massively simplifies the upkeep but I am struggling with making a dynamic slideshow page.

Comment: Maybe use `{% static pic.photo1.url %}`?

Comment: If you inspect (right-click and choose inspect) the HTML code, what are the values of `src` of each image?

Comment: The photo from from photo1 loads up no issue. The problem is that the photos are saved in the model under the names photo1, photo2 etc and the loop doesn't iterate over all the imagefiles in the model (database). What I would like to do is to create a loop that would create an <img src> for all the images in the database so that they can be displayed in the carousel.

Comment: The solution is to use another model, say `Carousel` that will have at least 2 fields inside: `sale = models.ForeignKey(Sales, models.CASCADE, related_name='images')` and `image = models.ImageField(upload_to='somewhere')`. Now you can add as many images as you wish.

Comment: Sales is the top level database with all the information (name, price, photo etc), and has many data entries. When you click on the picture it loads the slideshow view, this passes the pk of the data within sales so that the slideshow knows what data entry to look at. Maybe if it was possible to filter the {% for pic in cars %} to return only the images so that I could iterate over the images